# How reliable is a TCP connection?

Tags: c#, java, sockets, networking, tcp

I have been writen server-client application.Server is coded in c# and the client code writen using java.The communication protocol is TCP.

While transfering a file using tcp is it possible to send missing data. In other words does tcp guarantee that data arrives correctly.(Should I send header information for this file in order to check errors , like file size , hash etc.)

Comment: TCP can occasionally have errors. That is why you will sometimes see checksums with files.

Comment: TCP is [reliable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol)

Comment: Sriram I know that tcp is reliable packages.I mean it is checking errors , package loss etc. But I am not sure about reliability of on ordered package transfer.In other words assume you are sending a big file through tcp.While transmitting the file to client a package lost , of course it will be send again cause of tcp.However on the client side you opened a stream and write incoming data to file , then what happened to the package.It is not in the order it supposed to be. What is happening on the background ?. If I directly write incoming stream to file , is it correctly written ?

Comment: @DavutÖzcan TCP takes care all of that. It will never send bytes in wrong order. `TCP provides reliable, ordered, error-checked delivery of a stream of octets between programs running on computers connected to a local area network, intranet or the public Internet. It resides at the transport layer` from wiki

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ordering of the packages of a tcp transmission os reliable.

For example your tcp message is split in three packages A, B and C.

Your client receives A, package B gets lost and then the client receives C. In the stream you will get only package A, package C is stored and as soon package B is retransmitted and received by your client, in the stream you will get package B and then C.

The same is done if package B is routed throug another way and is therefor received after package C.

The field 'Sequence Number' in the tcp header is needed for this mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

TCP provides a 16-bit checksum in protocol. It can detect most of the errors. Mistakes are more likely made at upper levels rather than tcp/ip. If you need high reliability in your software, an end-to-end strategy could be considered.

There is a classic article which talks about this: "[end to end arguments in system design](http://web.mit.edu/Saltzer/www/publications/endtoend/endtoend.pdf)".